# React comments component - Target newly added comment component in list and run function on only this one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking to create a comment edit timer which triggers when a new comment is added. It will show an 'Edit' button for 60 seconds before the button is removed (similar to what The Verge do with their comments).

I have a `Comments` component which makes an API call after `componentDidMount()` and renders a list of `Comment` components (by adding comment objects into my `comment: []` state. I also have a `CommentForm` component which allows users to submit a new comment.

When a comment is successfully submitted the API call returns a complete comment object which I then prepend to the existing comment state array. I also update my `newCommentId` state with the new comment id and set my `startEditTimer` boolean state to true.

```
postCommentSuccess = (res) => {
  const newArray = this.state.comments.slice(0);
  newArray.splice(0, 0, res.data);
  this.setState({
    comments: newArray,
    newCommentId: res.data.id,
    startEditTimer: true,
  });
}
```

I render the list of comments like this...

```
render() {
  if (this.state.comments.length) {
    commentsList = (this.state.comments.map((comment) => {
      const { id } = comment;
      return (
        <Comment
          key={id}
          id={id}
          newCommentId={this.state.newCommentId}
          startEditTimer={this.state.startEditTimer}
        />
      );
    }));
  }

  return (
    <ul className="comments-list">
      {commentsList}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

In my `Comment` component I am checking to see if the `startEditTimer` prop is set to true and then running the `startEditTimer()` function.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.startEditTimer === true) {
    this.startEditTimer();
  }
}

startEditTimer = () => {
  this.setState({ editTimer: 60 });
  setInterval(this.countdown, 1000);
}

countdown = () => {
  this.setState({ editTimer: this.state.editTimer -= 1 });
}
```

In my return function I am then showing/hiding the edit button like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <li className="comment">
      {this.props.id === this.props.newCommentId &&
        this.state.editTimer > 0 &&
        <button onClick={this.editReply} className="edit-btn">Edit ({this.state.editTimer})</button>
      }
    </li>
  );
}
```

This works to an extent, the edit button does show on a new comment when it is posted, but the countdown timer does not last 60 seconds, instead it seems to be reduced by one every 0.5 seconds or so. I believe this could be because the `startEditTimer()` function is running multiple times when a new comment is added instead of just once so I believe I need a way of only running the function on the newly added comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to just pass the created time to the Comment component. Then, in the Comment component you add a setInterval-function that checks every second if the time passed since the create time is greater than 60 seconds. Could look something like this:

```
// Commentlist component
render() {
  if (this.state.comments.length) {
    commentsList = (this.state.comments.map((comment) => {
      const { id, createdTime } = comment;
      return (
        <Comment
          key={id}
          id={id}
          createdTime={createdTime}
          newCommentId={this.state.newCommentId}
        />
      );
    }));
  }

  return (
    <ul className="comments-list">
      {commentsList}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Then in the Comment component:

```
// Comment component
componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalChecker = setInterval(() => {
        if((Date.now() - this.props.createdDate)/1000 >= 60) {
            this.setState({ showEditButton: false})
            clearInterval(this.intervalChecker)
        }
    }, 1000)
}

render() {
  return (
    <li className="comment">
      {this.state.showEditButton && 
      <button onClick={this.editReply} className="edit-btn">Edit ({this.state.editTimer})</button>
      }
    </li>
  );
}
```

Also, see the following gist: https://jsbin.com/luhehitune/3/edit?js,output

Comment: This is a much better way of approaching the problem, thanks for the help. This way of approaching does however mean that if the same user submits a comment within 60 seconds of posting a previous comment, the previous comment loses its edit button. Out of interest, how would I go about creating separate timers and showEditButton states for each comment?

Comment: I would do something like this: https://jsbin.com/luhehitune/3/edit?js,output. This way, each comment component track it's own time. No need to do bookkeeping in the parent. Notice how each component prints the time that has passed.